# ngSrc is computed before ngIf causing unnecessary http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you write something like:

```html
<img ng-if="image.name != null" ng-src="img/{{ image.name }}_img.png" />
```

If `image.name = null` Angular will first add tag and evaluate src. The browser will make http request for `img/_img.png` wchich doesn't exists. Then angular will remove tag after parsing ngIf directive. What is the simplest way to resolve this issue? I thought that it's perfect use case for ngSrc and ngIf.

**EDIT**

In current unstable 1.2.0-rc.2 issue is fixed and everything works how it is supposed to do. In current stable 1.0.8 you can't even use ternary operator.

Comment: Make a directive that will check the ng-if and if the name is not null compile the ng-src. I'll try a plunkr if you want

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need the `ng-if` directive for this. Just do a ternary operator test in your expression. Something like

`<img ng-src="{{image.name?('img/'+ image.name +'_img.png'):null}}"/>`

and it should work. See my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BWiGdO?p=preview

Comment: Yes but the ng-src attribute is set ... That's the only difference. Your code works too

Comment: If ng-src is null then there is no call to server.

Comment: I know but it's just that you got an attribute for nothing it's just code style nothing more :)

Comment: yes, and it's shorter, this time I don't need directives because it's just one place in my code. If I would had more places I would definitively create directive because it improves readability and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with a simple directive.

Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <img ng-directive />
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the directive with the controller :

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.image = {name: "myName"};
  });

angular.module('App')
  .directive('ngDirective', function($compile){
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        if(scope.image.name != null){
          $compile($(element).attr('ng-src', 'http://lauterry.github.io/slides-prez-angular/img/angularjs.png'))(scope);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is the complete working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/LNgsuX

Comment: Thank you for fast answers. It's good enough solution for me. Anyway, I was googling and I didn't found if is it posiible to create directive with very high priority that runs other directives defined in the tag it is used in?

Comment: You got a priority attribute on a directvie. Tkae care about the ng-src attribute is set anyway is you add a condition in the ng-src that's the only difference if it's not a matter for you take it :)